# Xenserver VM network speed very slow

Tags: networking, xenserver

In XEN cloud the Internet in the virtual machines is very slow - just the external internet.
Both in windows-based machines and in Linux-based machines.

The situation is this:
When you access the VMs on ports 80/443 using the browser the speed is correct.
When you use any other ports, for example 22/21, the speed starts correctly and quickly drops to zero.

** This happens only in the virtual machines and not in the host **

I would love the wisdom of the masses :)

Comment: how your host nic allocated to the vm? and what kind of switch is uplinked to those uplink, please share the info. does the speed issue happen between two VM on the same host ?

Comment: Hey,
My Xen version is 6.5.
You right. its not append if i trying to connect from another vm, i tried to connect from another vm (Windows) and the speed is good.
You know what the problem?
The server connect directly to ISP.

Comment: what switch model you have? I have a feeling your switch choke

Comment: I don't have a switch.
The Xen host connected directly to ISP.
If the switch of the ISP was choke so the problem has happened also with the host.

Comment: Use your own switch please

Comment: First, thank you very much for any help.
I do not understand the context of the switch.
After all, the host works properly only the VMs do not work properly.
If there was a problem with the switch then the host would not work well either.

Comment: Sure the switch dont throttle/shape your traffic? can you give me the cpu/mem usage of the switch, etc My point is you have a hole where you cant diagnostic. Intra VM the traffic never hit the switch, it stay inside the xen kernel.

Comment: Ok, I'll check with the ISP.
Another question, I set up an internal network using the XenCenter How do I communicate directly with the host?

Comment: Do you got a manahement nic on the host? usually you bind a nic to be used in the LAN

Comment: This is private network in the host.
I setup this via xencenter -> networking tab -> add network -> single server private network.
I add the network to VMs and its work. but how i can use this private network to talk with the host?

Comment: Please provide a printscreen of the network tab of your xen, and a small drawing of how its plugged on the host, thx!

Comment: How i paste here image ? What is your email?

Comment: Host network tab
[link](http://imgur.com/a/G9I8o)

VM network tab
[link](http://imgur.com/a/JPDCO)